# How can I add custom command using python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I haven't found ANYTHING about this online. I've read the documentation but understandably absolutely failed to understand it. I also haven't found anything about (custom) commands in it directly.

I know that you can add a /start command for example by doing :

```
# Help command
def help_command(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("This is the help")

dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))
```

After which you can use /help to display the help. But what if I want to add my own command? (which I know is possible since I saw bots that have them)

I wanted to make a command that would make all text that the user sent uppercase. It would work by writing /uppercase after which the user would send the message and the bot would reply with the text all uppercase. So I went ahead and create a new function :

```
# Custom commands
def uppercase_command(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('Send any  message to make it uppercase. ⬆')
    text = update.message.text
    update.message.reply_text(text).upper()

dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("uppercase", uppercase_command))
```

Which doesn't work and the bot responds with "Unknown command". How can I add a custom command?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: did it show `Unknown command uppercase` or something different? Maybe problem is something different. Did you put message in the same line as `/uppercase` like `/uppercase my message` ? if you put message in next line then it will treats it as next command. OR maybe you put your command in wrong place - after code which starts bot.

Comment: better create minimal working code which shows your problem.

Comment: I see one mistake - you use `upper()` in wrong place - it has to be `text.upper()` but you have `reply_text(...).upper()` - and maybe error shows that `reply_text()` doesn't have `upper()`. If you would show FULL error message then we could confirm it.

Comment: Unfortunately by default when you run the not it doesn't display any error messages. I know that you can enable logging for this I think but I didn't manage to set it up yet. I will post the full error message output once I get from work. I do believe that I have in fact mistakenly put .upper() after the reply to method instead of the actual text as furas wrote in the comments.

Comment: you can always use `print()` to display which line of code is executed and what you have in variables. it is called `"print debuging"`.

Answer (score 0):

There is (almost) nothing wrong with the code that you showed. The only thing that comes to mind about `uppercase_command` is the wrong placement of `upper` that furas already pointed out in the comments.

> Which doesn't work and the bot responds with "Unknown command". How can I add a custom command?

If the bot actually sends `Unknown command` as a text message in the chat, this must be because you coded it to. That is, the update is already handled by another handler with probably prevents your `CommandHandler("uppercase", uppercase_command)` from handling the update. Please carefully read the documentation of [`Dispatcher.add_handler`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.dispatcher.html#telegram.ext.Dispatcher.add_handler) and double check that you add your handlers in the right order.

If you want that your command shows up in the auto-completion in the app, you can either use [`Bot.set_my_commands`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.set_my_commands) for that or set it up with @BotFather.

In order to show errors, please see [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot#logging) and [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Exception-Handling).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@dp.message_handler(text=['message'])
async def command_1(message : types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "answer?")
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly. - [from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32054047)